# How to represent a vector as a matrix?

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I have a vector of length 3. i want to represent it as a matrix of dimension 4*2. ie) if the length of vector is n then matrix should be of dimension (n+1)*2. The matrix should have elements arranged as follows:

```
Vector= [2 3 4]

Matrix = [0 2;2 3;3 4;4 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `reshape` from Matlab is the basis of my answer to your question:

> B = reshape(A,m,n) returns the m-by-n matrix B whose elements are taken column-wise from A. An error results if A does not have m*n elements ([from the official Matlab help](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)).

You basically add zeros at the beginning and at the end and then have every number in the vector occur twice (if you "unfold"/reshape the matrix). So lets construct the desired matrix by reversing this description:

```
%set input vector
v = [2 3 4];
%"double" the numbers, v_ is my temporary storage variable
v_ = [v; v];
%align all numbers along one dimension
v_ = reshape(v_, 2*length(v), 1)
%add zeros at beginning and end
v_ = [0 v_ 0];
%procude final matrix
m = reshape(v_, length(v)+1, 2);
```

in short

```
%set input vector
v = [2 3 4];
%"double" the numbers, v_ is my temporary storage variable
%all values are aligned as row vector
%zeros are added at beginning and end
v_ = [0, v, v, 0];
%produce final matrix
m = reshape(v_, length(v)+1, 2);
```

I haven't checked it, since I don't have a Matlab at hand right now, but you should get the idea.

**Edit**

The answer by *13aumi* manages this task even without the `reshape` command. However, you need to pay close attention to the shape of v (row- vs- column-vector).

Comment: Thanks.....it's working ...i m trying to give name to each row and each column...any suggesions..

Comment: You can use structs or cells to store related strings, cf. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strings.html BTW: You might want to open a new question, even if it may be related to another question you asked previously. That's the way StackOverflow works.. (of course you can add a hyperlink to the related questions)

Answer (score 4):

You can solve your problem easily with simple operations:

```
vector = [2 3 4];
matrix = [0 vector; vector 0]';
```

' is used to transpose the matrix.

Additionally there are two useful functions in Matlab to manipulate matrices and vectors:

reshape()

repmat()

Comment: +1 But I suggest you change `[0 vector; vector 0]'` to `[0 vector(:).'; vector(:).' 0].';` so that it also works if `vector` is a column, and even if it's complex (use transpose instead of conjugate transpose)